# Bash: Take argument or read -p prompt it

Tags: bash, variables, arguments, prompt, default-value

What's the most elegant way of: take supplied parameter or "read -p prompt" in case it's missing?

I can do some if--else

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    read -p "supply x:" x
else
    x="$1"
fi
```

However, I wonder if I can combine it somehow with some shorter syntax like

```
x=${1:-foo}
```

Is there any more concise way than if--else ? Or it if--else the way to go?

Comment: The most elegant thing to do if an argument is missing is to either provide a default or abort.  Attempting to read it is a mistake.

Comment: I was more wondering about possible one-liners - like bash-golf. Instead of read other operations can be made, e.g. either parameter provided, ether computed in some way (not necessarily read), read is simple for example and to play with. Thanks!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I whole-heartedly advise against this as the correct behavior is to either provide a default or terminate with an error message, but if you insist on doing this monstrosity, you can use:

```
x=${1-$(read -p prompt: v; echo "$v")}
```

This only allows a single line of input the be used, but that is probably desirable behavior.  With the caveat that the overall behavior is *not* desirable!  This is a terrible thing to do!

Comment: I was more wondering about possible one-liners - like bash-golf. Instead of read other operations can be made, e.g. either parameter provided, ether computed in some way (not necessarily read), read is simple for example and to play with. Thanks!.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$#` to check if the first positional parameter is set; using `-z` precludes the ability to pass an empty string as an argument:

```
if (( $# < 1 )); then
    IFS= read -rp "supply x: " x
else
    x=$1
fi
```

The additions to the `read` command ensure that whatever the user types is assigned *exactly* to `x`, without striping any leading or trailing whitespace or interpreting any backslashes specially. It's not often you actually *need* this, but it is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty laconic:

```
[[ -n "$1" ]] && x="$1" || read -p "supply x:" x
```

Your second solution is also 'bashy' enough if you need a default value.